# How to remove elements whose attributes have specific values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like below where I want to remove `<Student>` elements which `Name` and `Class` attributes are `&lt;Choose One&gt;`.

How do I achieve this in XSLT?

```
<Students>
    <Student Name="&lt;Choose One&gt;" Class="&lt;Choose One&gt;" />
<Students>
```

This is my sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Classes>         
    <Class Name="Class A">
        <UniqueSourceIdentifier>1345</UniqueSourceIdentifier>
        <Students>
            <Student Name="Test1" Units="Unit A" />
            <Student Name="&lt;Choose One&gt;" Units="&lt;Choose One&gt;" />
            <Student Name="&lt;Choose One&gt;" Units="&lt;Choose One&gt;" />
            <Student Name="&lt;Choose One&gt;" Units="&lt;Choose One&gt;" />
        </Students>  <!-- Added by edit -->
    </Class>         <!-- Added by edit -->
</Classes>           <!-- Added by edit -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all `<Student>` elements with the given properties, you can use the following empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="Student[contains(@Name,'&lt;Choose One&gt;') and contains(@Units,'&lt;Choose One&gt;')]" />
```

To copy all the other elements, you can use the *Identity template*

```
<!-- identity template  -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the provided solution does not work

Comment: What _exactly_ does not seem to work? You have to use some kind of `apply-templates` like the _identity template_ to match the empty template.

Comment: I updated my answer. The error was that you named an attribute `Class` instead of `Units` in your question. Now it should work as desired. I also added the identity template to the answer.

Comment: Please edit your question to change `Class` to `Units`. Otherwise the answer wouldn't match your question.

Comment: @FaisalShah - If it helps, here's a working example showing this answer working: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHUr